# OpenCV область интереса с++

Tags: c++, opencv

Пытаюсь взять область с одной картинки и скопировать ее на другую картинку
Код:

```
    //открытие изображений
image = cvLoadImage(filename, 1);
temple = cvLoadImage(filename2, 1);
//создание окон
cvNamedWindow("origianl", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("template", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("res", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//копирование
IplImage* dst1 = cvCloneImage(image);
//установка области интересов на обоих изображениях
    cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(0, 0, 300, 300));
cvSetImageROI(templ, cvRect(100, 100, 400, 400));
//сумма
cvAddWeighted(image, 0.5, templ, 0.5, 0, dst1);
//сброс областей
cvResetImageROI(templ);
cvResetImageROI(image);
//вывод
cvShowImage("origianl", image);
cvShowImage("template", templ);
cvShowImage("res", dst1);
```

Но получаю вот такую ошибку
[Скрин ошибки VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRPVf.png)
Но если сделать код таким, то все работает:

```
    //открытие изображений
image = cvLoadImage(filename, 1);
temple = cvLoadImage(filename2, 1);
//создание окон
cvNamedWindow("origianl", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("template", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("res", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

//установка области интересов на обоих изображениях
cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(100, 100, 400, 400));       //<------измененная строчка
cvSetImageROI(templ, cvRect(100, 100, 400, 400));       //<------измененная строчка
//сумма
cvAddWeighted(image, 0.5, templ, 0.5, 0, image);         //<------измененная строчка
//сброс областей
cvResetImageROI(templ);
cvResetImageROI(image);
//вывод
cvShowImage("origianl", image);
cvShowImage("template", templ);
cvShowImage("res", image);                              //<------измененная строчка
```

Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что необходимо в выходном массиве тоже указывать ROI.
И размеры ROI должны быть одинаковыми на всех трех изображениях. Если все же необходимо вырезать изображение размера, отличного от области куда его необходимо вставить, то предварительно вырезаемое изображение нужно привести к этом размеру ([cv::resize](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html)).

Вот так работает:

```
//открытие изображений
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage(filename, 1);
IplImage* temple = cvLoadImage(filename2, 1);

//создание окон
cvNamedWindow("origianl", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("template", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("res", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

//копирование
IplImage* dst1 = cvCloneImage(image);

const int widthROI = 200;                                  //<------измененная строчка
const int heightROI = 200;                                 //<------измененная строчка

cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(0, 0, widthROI, heightROI));
cvSetImageROI(temple, cvRect(100, 100, widthROI, heightROI));
cvSetImageROI(dst1, cvRect(0, 0, widthROI, heightROI));    //<------измененная строчка
//сумма
cvAddWeighted(image, 0.5, temple, 0.5, 0.5, dst1);
//сброс областей
cvResetImageROI(temple);
cvResetImageROI(image);
cvResetImageROI(dst1);                                     //<------измененная строчка
//вывод
cvShowImage("origianl", image);
cvShowImage("template", temple);
cvShowImage("res", dst1);

cvWaitKey(0);
```

Comment: Пишите только на Фортране (а лучше на Питоне)
Иль назовут вас Сосунками
Коль захотите вы в запале 
Попробовать себя в Паскале

Этот стишок был вырезан на парте в Университете в 1992 году :-)

Comment: А еще там (на парте вырезано) было - Я Фортран бы выучил только за то, что на нем защитился Декан мой :-)